# Tool which identify override in Application for a framework component

Tags: javascript, css

I have just started to work on a tool which basically helps to identify functions and CSS of a component overridden in the Application. Application overriding is perfectly all right, as it may want to customize particular component. Framework provides a basic component and application may or may not use it, as it is, depending on the requirement.

Now, it may happen that application erroneously given some bad code while overriding, which in turn effects the proper working of component. Consider the below, very basic button component provided as from framework side. In Application side, created an instance and did some modification as per requirement, but because of some bad code & styling (not able to see Application text on button fully), it fails (see console log for error).

http://jsfiddle.net/8yyt3a3e/

```
/*Framework Provided Support*/
function framework(){
    var btnf= document.createElement("button");
    btnf.id='btn_f';
    btnf.setAttribute('class','btnframe');
    var btnfContent = document.createTextNode("Framework");
    btnf.onclick=function(){
       alert(this.textContent);
    };
    btnf.changeContent= function(newContent){
       this.textContent= newContent;
    };
    btnf.appendChild(btnfContent);
    return btnf;
}
/*Application code*/
function application(){
    var container= document.getElementById('app');
    var btn= framework();
    btn.id='btn_a';
    //App overrides style
    btn.style.cssText='background-color:blue;width:100px';
    //App override click event handler
    btn.onclick=function(){
     control.render();    //bad code in application side   
     alert(this.textContent);
    };
    //API to change content of new Button
    btn.changeContent('Application');
    container.appendChild(btn);
}
var btnComponent=new application();
```

This is very simple case, but in production side, application and framework code sizes can be huge, making very difficult to find the root cause behind any failure of component in Application. It takes a good amount of time to find whether the issue is of framework or application!.
There comes the usage of the tool i want to create, which lists down all overridden data making it easier to look directly on the differences. I am not able to guess where should i start. Which scripting language would be better? What should be the approach..?

Hope that clarifies my problem statement! Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please stop editing backticks around random words in your post. Backticks are not for emphasis, they are for marking up inline code.

Comment: This is because the class was not created correctly to handle any type of text regardless of string length , this has nothing to do with overriding , anyway speaking about that , some framework is already underconstruction here : http://www.jspplang.org/

Comment: what the problem ? to read console output and get a string where error appears ? Also, if you call something framework, please avoid to use hardcoded ids like here `btnf.id='btn_f';`

Comment: @eicto Yes..I understand. In here for this particular sample code, it is very  easy to detect problem because console will show erroneous line, but there are cases of bad codes in application for which there won't be any console errors..and considering big amount of application and framework source code, it becomes time consuming task to identify the real cause..

Comment: hm, I think you searchin for holy graal for bug detect, the most logical bug not in code, it is in coder head, it appears not because code wrong, but because one who coded mistaken. If there is no exception (in one or another form) you will not get error message, and finding incorrect behaviour turns in two ways - read code, or use debugger.

Comment: but there are some helpers - statistical analysers (like eslint), strict type languages which compiles to js, machine readable jsdoc checkers (so you can hint your framework with comments, or universal validating functions, which describe how to call your function and so , if type is wrong, they will warn).

Comment: btw, you want something like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/8yyt3a3e/1/ (you can also use setters/getters for your methods, so you can track mutations by your own framework)

Comment: @eicto Probably not, as i don't want any changes to framework. I am thinking in a way where i will instantiate component in application after which i can get a list of methods/properties of object and later compare it with framework provided methods/properties.

Comment: the problem with your code here - you changing html element property, it is not part of your framework :) Your better is to use prototyped inheritance

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `btnf.appendChild(btnfContent)` (at the end of the `framework()` function) to `document.body.appendChild(btnfContent)`. Otherwise it would mean putting the button that you're creating inside the button that you're creating. (instead of `document.body` you can put the ID of an existing element other than the button that you're creating).

Have you defined the `control.render()` function in another part of your code (like `function control.render(){...}` or `control.render=function(){...}`)? Otherwise that won't either work because `control.render()` isn't a predefined function.